# Cannot create a managed object context on iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

I created a non core data project. I now want to use core data. In the build phases, I linked my binary with CoreData.framework. In my application delegate method, I want to manually create a managed object context like so

```
NSManagedObjectContext *aContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
```

When I do the above, I get the following error,

```
Receiver 'NSManagedObjectContext' for class message is a forward declaration.
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you included #import <CoreData/CoreData.h> in your application delegate's header?

Comment: Thanks that works. A better solution would be to put it in the `prefix.pch` file.

Comment: Also, be wary of using a class called message. This will conflict with other classes in iOS. I have had this affect me before.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You need to import CoreData/CoreData.h in your application delegate's header file:

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

Since you probably use it through outyour application you should put it in the precompiled header file, YourApp-Prefix.pch:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#endif
```

Comment: If your app uses Core Data throughout, you can also add the same line to the YourAppName-Prefix.pch file in your project's Supporting Files directory.

Answer (score 6):

Just write #import < CoreData/CoreData.h > in your implementation file. It will work